# Testing requested query in pre_get_posts

Tags: filters, user-roles, dashboard, pre-get-posts

Depending on user roles, I am hiding admin posts in dashboard->edit.php, however if non-admin user requests to list it's own posts this should be allowed.

To achieve this I am trying to test what was the requested query in `pre_get_posts` however `$query` seems empty. How can I test at this stage what is the requested query?

Code:

```
function posts_for_current_role($query) {
global $pagenow;

        if( 'edit.php' == $pagenow   ){
            .
            . // if user in dashboard requested to list it's own posts, allow this otherwise hide admin posts
            var_dump($query) // Empty at this stage cannot view here if user requested it's own posts...
            .
            if (---------------){ // what can I test here?
                $query->set('author',  '-1');
            }
        }
        return ($query);     
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_role');
```

Comment: Don't forget that `pre_get_posts` will fire for every WP query on edit page. I would suggest great plugin [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) for (not only) query debugging. You will see query vars affecting main query when viewing posts on edit page, and so you will be able to build some "if" conditions.

Comment: A very rude method: `if (empty($_GET['author'])) {
                    $query->set('author',  '-1');
            }` What do you think?